# JMeter reusing previous thread payload instead of new thread payload

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am trying to adapt a script I already have to run using .csv data input. When the script is ran without the .csv, it runs perfectly for any configurations I choose to use. When it runs using the .csv, whatever scenario is in the first row will run perfect, but everything from there on will fail. The reason for the failure is because some of my variables are being reused from the first thread and I don't know how to stop this from happening.

This is what my script looks like:

HTTP Request - GET ${url} (url is declared in the CSV data input, and changes each run)

-> postprocessor that extracts Variable_1, Variable_2 and Variable_3

Sampler1

-> JSR223 preprocessor: creates payloadSampler1 using javascript, example:

```
var payloadSampler1 = { };
payloadSampler1.age = vars.get("Variable_2");
payloadSampler1.birthDate = "1980-01-01";
payloadSampler1.phone = {};
payloadSampler1.phone.number = "555-555-5555";
vars.put("payloadSampler1", JSON.stringify(payloadSampler1));
```

Sampler2

-> JSR223 preprocessor: creates payloadSampler1 using javascript (same as above but for different values)

Sampler3

-> JSR223 preprocessor: creates payloadSampler1 using javascript (same as above but for different values)

Sampler4

-> JSR223 preprocessor: creates payloadSampler1 using javascript (same as above but for different values)

HTTP Request - POST ${url}/${Variable_1}/submit

-> JSR223 preprocessor: creates payloadSubmit using javascript, and mix and matching the results from the above samplers - like so:

```
var payloadSubmit = { };
if (vars.get("someVar") != "value" && vars.get("someVar") != "value2" && vars.get("differentVar") != "true") {
    payloadSubmit.ageInfo = [${payloadSampler1}];
}
if (vars.get("someVar2") != "true") {
    payloadSubmit.paymentInfo = [${payloadSampler2}];
}
payloadSubmit.emailInfo = [${payloadSampler3"}];
payloadSubmit.country = vars.get("Variable_3");
vars.put("payloadSubmit", JSON.stringify(payloadSubmit));
```

-> BodyData as shown in the screenshot:

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhFoL.png)

I have a Debug PostProcessor to see the values of all these variables I am creating. For the first iteration of my script, everything is perfect. For the second one, however, the Debug PostProcessor shows the values for all payloadSamplers and all the Variables correctly changed to match the new row data (from the csv), but, the final variable, payloadSubmit just reuses whatever the values where for the first thread iteration.

Example:

Debug PostProcessor at the end of first iteration shows:

```
Variable_1=ABC
Variable_2=DEF
Variable_3=GHI
payloadSampler1={"age":"18","email":null,"name":{"firstName":"Charles"}},{"age":"38","email":null}}
payloadSampler2={"paymentChoice":{"cardType":"CreditCard","cardSubType":"VI"}},"amount":"9.99","currency":"USD"}
payloadSampler3={"email":"tes@email.com"}
payloadSubmit={"ageInfo":[{"age":"18","email":null,"name":{"firstName":"Charles"}},{"age":"38","email":null}],"paymentInfo":[{"paymentChoice":{"cardType":"CreditCard","cardSubType":"VI"}},"amount":"9.99","currency":"USD"],"emailInfo":[{"email":"tes@email.com"}],"country":"GHI"}
```

But at the end of the 2nd iteration it shows:

```
Variable_1=123
Variable_2=456
Variable_3=789
payloadSampler1={"age":"95","email":null,"name":{"firstName":"Sam"}},{"age":"12","email":null}}
payloadSampler2={"paymentChoice":{"cardType":"CreditCard","cardSubType":"DC"}},"amount":"19.99","currency":"USD"}
payloadSampler3={"email":"tes2@email.com"}
payloadSubmit={"ageInfo":[{"age":"18","email":null,"name":{"firstName":"Charles"}},{"age":"38","email":null}],"paymentInfo":[{"paymentChoice":{"cardType":"CreditCard","cardSubType":"VI"}},"amount":"9.99","currency":"USD"],"emailInfo":[{"email":"tes@email.com"}],"country":"USA"}
```

I can also see that the final HTTP Request is indeed sending the old values.

My very limited understanding is that because I am invoking the variables like so "${payloadSampler1}" it will use the value that was set for that the first time the sampler was ran (back in the 1st thread iteration). These are the things I have tried:

If I use vars.get("payloadSubmit") on the body of an HTTP Sampler, I get an error, so that is not an option. If I use vars.get("payloadSampler1") on the Samplers that create the variables, extra escape characters are added, which breaks my JSON. I have tried adding a counter to the end of the variable name and having that counter increase on each thread iteration, but the results is the same. All the variables and samplers other than the last one have updated values, but the last one will always reuse the variables from the first thread iteration.

I also tried to use ${__javaScript(vars.get("payloadSubmit_"+vars.get("ThreadIteration")))}, but the results are always the same.

And I have also tried using the ${__counter(,)} element, but if I set it to TRUE, it will always be 1 for each thread iteration, and if I set it to FALSE, it starts at 2 (I am assuming it is because I use counter in another sampler within this thread - but even after removing that counter this still happens).

I am obviously doing something (or many things) wrong.

If anyone can spot what my mistakes are, I would really appreciate hearing your thoughts. Or even being pointed to some resource I can read for an approach I can use for this. My knowledge of both javascript and jmeter is not great, so I am always open to learn more and correct my mistakes.

Finally, thanks a lot for reading through this wall of text and trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's hard to tell where exactly your problem is without seeing the values of these `someVar` and `payload`, most probably something cannot be parsed as a valid JSON therefore on 2nd iteration your last JSR223 PostProcessor fails to run till the end and as the result your `payloadSubmit` variable value doesn't get updated. Take a closer look at JMeter GUI, there is an yellow triangle with exclamation sign there which indicates the number of errors in your scripts. Also it opens [JMeter Log Viewer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) on click

   [image]

   if there is a red number next to the triangle - obviously you have a problem and you will need to see the *jmeter.log* file for the details.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting mainly due to the fact that [Groovy has higher performance comparing to other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). Check out [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) guide to learn more on how to work with JSON data in Groovy.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitri. I am going to look both into any errors that may be present, and into using Groovy as well.

Comment: Just leaving a note here, in case anyone is curious. I solved the issue. I had the option to "Cache compiled script script if available" checked. Unchecking it did the trick. Thank you to anyone that spent time thinking about this!